# Java symbol not in system preferences anymore, but still installed

Tags: java, macos, java-14

I have to handle a confusing issue concerning the installation of Java on my mac:

- If I go to system preferences, there is no Java symbol anymore:
  [image]
- But if I type `java -version` in the terminal, I get

  `java version "14" 2020-03-17
  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 14+36-1461)
  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 14+36-1461, mixed mode, sharing)`

So, it seems that Java is still installed.

My system: macOS High Sierra version 10.13.6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Java symbol that you are looking for in your system preferences is the "Java Control panel". It has been removed in the newest versions of Java:

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/11-relnote-issues-5012449.html#JDK-8185077

> [...] Please note that the **Java Control Panel**, which was used for configuring the deployment technologies, has also been removed along with the shared system JRE (but not the server JRE) and the JRE Auto Update mechanism.